# volume mounting clickhouse docker image to override config.xml to connect with tabix

Tags: docker-compose, clickhouse

```yaml
clickhouse:
    build: ./db/clickhouse
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      # Store data to HDD
      - ./clickhouse-data:/var/lib/clickhouse/
      # Base Clickhouse cfg
      - ./clickhouse/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - ./clickhouse/users.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml
    ports:
      - "8123:8123" # for http clients
      - "9000:9000" # for console client
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_USER=oussema
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=root
      - CLICKHOUSE_DB=DWH
      - CLICKHOUSE_DEFAULT_ACCESS_MANAGEMENT=1
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144

  tabix:
      image: spoonest/clickhouse-tabix-web-client
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      depends_on:
        - clickhouse
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        - CH_NAME=clickhouse
        - CH_HOST=https://127.0.0.1:8123
        - CH_LOGIN=oussema
        - CH_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: + port 8123 is HTTP port not HTTPS (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http/).

Comment: I have changed the tabix port to 8124:80 and delete the volumes of clickhouse conatiner   i just left " ./clickhouse-data:/var/lib/clickhouse/" and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

It just working example for test purpose:

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.0"

services:
  clickhouse:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider localhost:8123/ping || exit 1
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 16
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_USER=default
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=12345

  tabix:
      image: spoonest/clickhouse-tabix-web-client
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      depends_on:
        - clickhouse
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        - CH_NAME=clickhouse
        - CH_HOST=http://localhost:8123
        - CH_LOGIN=default
        - CH_PASSWORD=12345
```

It needs:

```bash
# run container
docker compose up

# browse the tabix endpoint
http://localhost:8080/
```